# Code Runs well on debug but crashes during full execution

Tags: vba, excel

I have a line of code that runs flawlessly on debug, but consistently crashes excel on full execution. Essentially what it is supposed to do is combine two rows of data. I am doing this because I imported data from a database, in that database it records transactions on two separate lines: one side of the transaction is on one line while the other side is on the other line, all of data for the previous columns is located on either one of these lines. So for example:

```
|trans 1 | 1/1/2015| $500.00| 0

|trans 1 |---------| 0| 497.00|
```

Ideally it should look like

```
|trans 1|1/1/2015|500.00|497.00|
```

Second row should be deleted.

This is my code to do this:

```
Sub Collapse_Rows()
    Dim ALLCS As Worksheet

    Set ALLCS = Sheets("Asset LLC (Input)")
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    For x = 66515 To 16 Step -1
        If ALLCS.Cells(x, 2) = ALLCS.Cells(x + 1, 2) Then
            If ALLCS.Cells(x, 28) <> Empty Then
                ALLCS.Cells(x + 1, 28) = ALLCS.Cells(x, 28)
            End If
        End If

        If ALLCS.Cells(x - 1, 2) = ALLCS.Cells(x, 2) Then
            If ALLCS.Cells(x, 28) <> Empty Then
                ALLCS.Cells(x - 1, 28) = ALLCS.Cells(x, 28)
            End If
        End If

        If ALLCS.Cells(x, 5) <> Empty And ALLCS.Cells(x, 2) = Empty Then
        ElseIf ALLCS.Cells(x, 24) = Empty Then
            ALLCS.Cells(x, 24).EntireRow.Select
            Selection.Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I run this code partially on debug and it works well. When I run the code fully excel crashes any ideas as to why/how to prevent this from happening??

Comment: you should try and add a debug statement (eg. debug.print) to understand at which point it crashes

Comment: What exactly would that do @Xarylem

Comment: is elseif correct here --   *ElseIf ALLCS.Cells(x, 24) = Empty Then* or it should be only if ?

Comment: Its correct I want it to skip that elseif statement if the first if condition is met.

Comment: Add the command DoEvents in your loop. Also sometimes helps.

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` is generally a bad idea.  When something fails it quietly proceeds without warning you there is an issue.  Try removing that, and see what happens.

Comment: You say you get this data from a database, can you apply a "group by" before you import it.  Essentially what you seem to need here is a SQL group by, if I had to do it in Excel I would use ADO to connect to the worksheet and run a group by statement on it.

Comment: @dom176 The idea of a debug statement is to understand at which point your code crashes printing out eg. the current cycle number or something similar. For sure you should remove the {On Error Resume Next} statement, and use break-point to verify until where your code has no problems. Additionally, you might have to put in some {DoEvents} as your routine seems to be slightly heavy.

Answer (score 2):

At first glance, it seems like a major part of the problem lies in the fact that the code itself is somewhat resource instensive.

First, it starts at row 66515. Is there a reason it starts here? That means that in most circumstances, there will be around 33,250 row deletion executions (every other row from 16 --> 66515). That will take a long time, and in many cases Excel will become unresponsive.

A few options.

Determine whether or not you actually need to start the loop at row 66515. Is that a fixed starting point for a reason? If not, use code to determine the last row of your actual dataset and start there.

Also, at the beginning of your code, turn `SceenUpdating` off using: `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`.
At the end of your code, turn it back on using `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`

Comment: One more thing to add to the above is to replace `ALLCS.Cells(x, 24).EntireRow.Select` with `ALLCS.Cells(x, 24).EntireRow.delete`  and remove `Selection.delete` to get rid of the unnecessary selection step.

Comment: 66515 is a fixed starting point, and I had that suggestion in place, the entirerow.select move was an attempt fix to the problem.